# Submit button has to be pressed after a sort is completed

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

i have a primefaces datatable which displays users infomration, this is working fine but when using the inbuilt sort by function of the datatable i have to press submit to get the data into the datatable as when i press the sort i only get the message "no results found" but once i press submit it populates the datatable and in the correct order is there anyway i can do this without pressing hte submit button each time

here is the code

```
           <h:inputHidden id="search" value="#{bean.searchString}"  />   
                <p:commandButton value="View all" action="#{bean.usernameSearch}" update="group" />
            </p>

            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <h:panelGroup id="group">
                <p:dataTable id="UserTableSearch"
                             rowKey="#{bean.userSearchResults}"
                             rendered="#{facesContext.postback}"
                             widgetVar="UserTableSearch" 
                             paginator="true" 
                             rows="10"
                             value="#{bean.userSearchResults}"
                             var="item"
                             emptyMessage="No results found."
                             scrollable="true">


                    <p:column id="username"   
                              headerText="#{bundle.labelUsername}"
                              sortBy="username"
                              width="150">                      
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.username}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="firstname"
                              headerText="#{bundle.labelFirstName}"
                              sortBy="firstname"
                              width="150">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.firstName}"/>
                    </p:column >

                    <p:column id="surname"
                              headerText="#{bundle.labelSurname}"
                              sortBy="surname"
                              width="150">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.surname}"/>
                    </p:column >
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call the `submit` method. [reference](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$('.submit-button').submit();
```

You can attach this to, say, the `onclick` event of the sort button.

Comment: That is the issue there is no onclick event for the sort button it is the function that is built into the primefaces datatable

Comment: Surely you can still attach events to the buttons. Look at [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSorting.jsf) page. If you run `document.getElementById('j_idt19:dataTable:j_idt24').onclick = function(){console.log(1);}` in the console and click on the manufacturer button, it does the sorting And prints 1 in the console

Comment: Also if you're worried about interfering with the default behaviour of the sorting headers/buttons, use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: Sorry how would i do that in netbeans ? sorry i am all new to this